# what is the time complexity of this code

Tags: time-complexity

what is the time complexity of the following code. please help me.

// a is mxn matrix

```
for i = 1 to m:
    l = {}

    for j = 1 to n:
        if(a[i,j] != 0):
            add j to l

    if(len(l) > 1):
        for k=1 to len(l)
            for j=k+1 to len(l):
                some other code
```

Comment: Nobody can answer as long as the *condition* is not specified.

Comment: can u help me now @YvesDaoust

Comment: Typeset the code correctly and legibly.

Comment: I have renamed the variable of the last nested loop from `l` to `j` because the previous name of `l` was shadowing the list `l` and it rendered `len(l)` meaningless. Please correct the code if this is not what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the time complexity of "some other code" is constant. You can bound the total time required by noticing that the outer loop performs $m$ iterations.

The first inner loop performs $n$ iterations and, in the worst case, inserts $n$ elements into $l$.

The last two inner nested loops perform a number of iterations that is monotonically increasing with the length of $l$ and is therefore maximized when the length of$l$ is $n$. In this case the number of iterations is:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=k+1}^n 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n (n-k) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = O(n^2).
$$

The overall time complexity is therefore $O(m \cdot (n +n^2)) = O(mn^2)$.

Comment: what if a is a sparse matrix @Steven

Comment: Can you give me a formal definition of sparse? The answer depends on that :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Comment: I know what as sparse matrix is. I was just saying that this term is often used in a non completely formal sense to mean that a $m\times n$ matrix has "few" non-zero element when compared to $m\cdot n$. But how many is few, exactly? Since you linked the wikipedia page I am going to pedantically follow what wikipedia says: a matrix is sparse if **most** of its elements are zero. Then, consider a $m\times n$ matrix $M$ that has $\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1$ non-zero elements per row. According to the above definition $M$ is sparse, yet the running time of your algorithm on $M$ is still $\Omega(mn^2)$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation